# Trying to get the model to make accurate predictions

Tags: model

Accurate predictions

I tried to get the model to make predictions if the future closing price will be higher or lower than the current close. Sometimes it is decent and other times it is really bad at the predictions. I user multiple models like Random forest, XGBoost, K-NearstNeaighbors